# Aligning two divs going wrong..?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to align two `div`'s side by side.
Both the `div`'s are contained in an another `div`.

This is the HTML and CSS code that i have written and it's going horribly wrong.

HTML :

```
<div id="content">     
 <div id="main"></div>
 <div id="sidebar"></div>     
</div>
```

CSS :

```
 #content {
    width: 1000px;        
}
#sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
#main {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3zCN)

EDIT :
the code that has finally worked for me is as follows :

```
<div id="content">

 <div id="sidebar"></div>
 <div id="main"></div>

</div>
```

and the css is as follows :

```
#content {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}
#main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

I dont know the reason but...

```
overflow : auto;
```

was needed to get it displayed in a right way.

Comment: which one will be at the left??

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `margin-left: 200px;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R3zCN/1/)**

That's pushing the blue div to the right and causing the red div to drop down since there's not enough room for both to exist next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin-left from the css:

```
#main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Narendera your `parent div's` width is **1000px** and you have given `margin-left` to your  **child div's** `#main` so that's why its going down so you should remove the `margin-left:200px` from  **child div** `#main`

**CSS**

```
  #content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1000px;
}

#main {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
}


#sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and through this its working fine.....see the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RvcLH/)

Answer (score 1):

### Versatile Floats

With your mark-up, you can place the floats in any order that you require.

For example:

```
<h3>div.main comes first in mark-up order.</h3>
<div id="content" class="ex1">
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

if you apply this CSS:

```
.ex1 #sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.ex1 #main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

your side bar will appear to the right because the elements are floated left in the order that they appear in the mark-up.

In this example, I switch the HTML around so that the main element is second:

```
<h3>div.main comes second in mark-up order and is not floated.</h3>
<div id="content" class="ex2">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

and with this CSS:

```
.ex2 #sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.ex2 #main {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

In this case, the side bar is floated left and appears first.  The main element is not floated but with the left margin, it allows space for the side bar.

However, you may want the main element to be first in the mark-up (for SEO reasons...):

```
<h3>div.main comes first in mark-up order but appears 2nd.</h3>
<div id="content" class="ex3">
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

and apply this CSS:

```
.ex3 #sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.ex3 #main {
    width: 800px;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

In this case, if you float to the right, the main is floated to the right first and the sidebar is also floated right but is to the left edge of the main, like the 2nd example but with different markup.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/GP29e/

Answer (score 0):

Checked your code. You just remove float: left from #sidebar.

```
#sidebar {
width: 200px;
#float: left;
height: 400px;
background-color: red;
}
```